# Grasshopper C# VisualStudio how to add or to display a "component-bottom" info

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, grasshopper

**Thank you in advance for all tips that you will share with me about this topic.**

I was wondering how to add a Grasshopper component bottom info like this one below:

[example as ref for component-bottom info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Acb3K.png)

I am asking about the code to add in C# by VisualStudio when your are attempting to develop your GHA file. In python is fairly easy to do this. But in C# VS?

Understand what code and know where I need to add it to my VisualStudio project while developing a GHA component.

Here is an example that works in Grasshopper but not in VisualStudio:
https://discourse.mcneel.com/t/message-under-component-visual-studio-c/50050

Here is another example, but I can't understand how to write correctly it in VisualStudio:
https://www.grasshopper3d.com/forum/topics/gh-component-message-property-implementation

Comment: Typically a minimum reproducible example of what you are trying to do is required before any advice can be dispensed. You most likely want to add  What have you tried? You could follow several great tutorials and videos online: https://developer.rhino3d.com/guides/grasshopper/your-first-component-windows/ and  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pFCrIzENDn8

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The point is that in python I can add that bottom-component info, but in C# I don't know where to start. I will go on searching. :)

Comment: Ok, this example works in Grasshopper but in VisualStudio seems not. Any suggestions, please? 
https://discourse.mcneel.com/t/message-under-component-visual-studio-c/50050

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `this.Message = "your message";` inside any of your component class's boiler-plate methods e.g. inside the constructor, `RegisterInputParams`, or`SolveInstance`.

**Example Placement**

```
...
namespace GH_Demo
{
    public class GH_DemoComponent : GH_Component
    {
        public GH_DemoComponent()
          : base("GH_Demo", "demo",
            "Just showing message placement")
        {
            this.Message = "Pre-Run Message";
        }
       ...

       ...
        protected override void SolveInstance(IGH_DataAccess DA)
        {
            ...
            this.Message = "Post-Run Message";
        }
...
```